# JTextArea - How to add Code/Syntax highlighting?

Tags: java, swing, syntax-highlighting, jtextarea

Im developing an app in java, a simple text editor. What I want to do is to add syntax highlighting, so it will color java (pubic, static, void, int, float). How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I dont even know how to change the color of the text...

Comment: There are complete implementations out there, just google it...

Comment: Take a look at RSyntaxTextArea: https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea
It offers syntax highlighting modes for many different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at this old discussion, but it sounds tricky.
Check [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/java-jtextarea-and-syntax-highlighting-417575/) out.
But I don't know if JTextArea is what you're looking for, read some docs for JTextPane or JEditorPane. You may want to use them.